# Update information user profile Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, token

Hello i just implements the method to modify and update the user profile on swift 4 and i have a problem updating the user information (firstname and lastname) in token

```
 //Get token
let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token

// Bearer token to update information
let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/updateProfile")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

//serialization token
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
        let sub = json["sub"] as? [String: AnyObject]

         DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Get current user
        let myUser = PFUser.current()

        // check if firstName, lastName are not empty
        if(self.firstNameTextfield.text!.isEmpty || self.lastNameTextfield.text!.isEmpty )
        {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "First name and Last name are required fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
            return
        }

        // set new values user
        let userFirstName = self.firstNameTextfield.text
        let userLastName = self.lastNameTextfield.text

        // update information    
        myUser?.setObject(userFirstName, forKey: "\(sub?["firstname"])")
        myUser?.setObject(userLastName, forKey: "\(sub?["lastname"])")

        //display activity indicator
        let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            loadingNotification.labelText = "sauvegarde des informations"
            myUser?.saveInBackground(block: { (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            // Hide activity indicator
            loadingNotification.hide(animated: true)

            if(error != nil)
            {
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
                return
            }
            if(success)
            {
                let userMessage = "votre profil a été mis a jour"
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
                        //                            self.opener.loadUserDetails()
                    })
                })
                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil);
            }
                } as! PFBooleanResultBlock)
       }

    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
    }.resume()
```

I do not know if it's the right way to update the information, and he recovers **userFirstName**, **userLastName** when I seize but `myUser?.setObject(userFirstName, forKey: "\(sub?["firstname"])")` displays nil on the console. I really need your help thank you in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean it displays nil, it's a set method so what is it that displays nil? And what is the meaning of `"\(sub?["firstname"])"`, it looks like the key you want to use is a value in a dictionary?

Comment: `myUser?.setObject(userFirstName, forKey: "\(sub?["firstname"])")` should recover and set the value of **userFirstName** `"\(sub?["firstname"])"` is the value of the firstname extracted in the token like `Json[firstname]`

Comment: That makes no sense, you are adding/setting the value of `userFirstName`for the key that you get from `sub?["firstname"]` on your `myUser` object. What do you mean "recover and set"? And I still don't understand what it is that "displays nil on the console"?

Comment: `userFirstName` will retrieve the new values entered on the keyboard and I will parse them for in the information of the token (`sub?["firstname"]`) to edit

Comment: I still don't understand your issue, you want to update first name and last name for your `myUser` object with values you get from two textfields this part I get but I don't get what it is that fails. You need to explain that part better by clarifying your question and possibly giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing these lines in the above code -

```
var myUser = PFUser.current()
myUser?["\(sub?["firstname"])"] = userFirstName
myUser?["\(sub?["lastname"])"] = userLastName
```

Comment: @GeekThuG can you please post PFuser model